# Last Login, with Menu, Change Header

Tags: powershell, authentication

How do I get the Last Login from ntuser.dat to read "User" instead of '(Split-path $_.Directory -Leaf)'?
And how do I get my local time instead of this confusing UTC and not UTC?

```
#Query-LastLogin.ps1
function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'My Menu'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"

    $Menu = @{}

    (Get-ChildItem C:\Users).Name | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} { 

        Write-Host "$_`: Press '$i' for this option." 
        $Menu.add("$i",$_)
        $i++
    }

    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."

    $Selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"

    if ($Selection -eq 'Q') { Return } Else { $Menu.$Selection }

}
#$UserSelection = Show-Menu -Title 'Local Users' 
#(Get-ChildItem C:\Users).Name
$userinput = Show-Menu -Title 'Local Users'
(Get-ChildItem C:\users\$userinput\ntuser.dat -Force | select @{e={(Split-path $_.Directory -Leaf)}},last* | sort lastwritetime -Descending)
```

Response to script:

```
(Split-path $_.Directory -Leaf) : myusername
LastAccessTime                  : 5/4/2022 12:40:02 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc               : 5/4/2022 4:40:02 PM
LastWriteTime                   : 5/3/2022 10:44:22 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc                : 5/4/2022 2:44:22 AM
```

See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-deployment/issue-with-date-modified-for-ntuser-dat/m-p/102438 for the confusion (scroll to the end)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to give the calculated property a name:

```
@{name = 'User'; Expression = {(Split-path $_.Directory -Leaf)}}
```

As for excluding the Utc times, you can append

```
-ExcludeProperty *utc
```